# How can I add a horizontal rule to a docx using Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

In Microsoft Word, if you type `---` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a horizontal rule will appear with full width. I'm trying to recreate the same in C# using Interop Word.

Having inspected the XML of a docx document, the relevant XML seems to be like this:

```xml
<w:spacing w:before="120" w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto"/>
```

It is called `SpacingBetweenLines` in OOXML specification, however I still can't find anything relevant in Interop Word. Where will it be likely to find the related documentation?

Update: The following code snippet works and does solve my current problem, and puts a horizontal rule between "first line" and "second line".

```cs
para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
Word.Range first_line_range = para.Range;
para.Range.Select();
para.Range.Text = "first line";
para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
app.Selection.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
para2 = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
para2.Range.Text = "second line";
para2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

I have no idea why it works, it is all trial and error, mainly I don't know why the order of functions call (`Select`, `Paragraphs.Add`, `Range.InsertParagraphAfter`) has to be in this particular order.

Comment: Record a macro and look at the generated code.

Comment: Just tried, it stops converting "---" to a line when recording a macro.

Comment: Write a macro to read the individual lines.